# Скопировать из одного списка в другой

Tags: java, list, списки

Есть список List. В нем любое количество строк. Хочу скопировать из этого списка в другие по 10 строк. То есть сначала первые 10 потом вторые 10 и до конца. Подскажите как реализовать. Заранее благодарю

Answer (score 1):

```
public class JavaApplication66 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Список с которого будут копироваться данные
        List<String> lst = new ArrayList<>();

        //Заполняем список значениями
        for (int i = 0; i < 35; i++) {
            lst.add(""+i);
        }

        //копируем первый подсписок
        List<String> lst1 = lst.subList(0, 10);
        //второй подсписок
        List<String> lst2 = lst.subList(10, 20);
        //третий подсписок
        List<String> lst3 = lst.subList(20, 30);

        //проверяем результат
        for(String st: lst1){
            System.out.println(st);
        }
        System.out.println("-/-/-/-");
        for(String st: lst2){
            System.out.println(st);
        }
        System.out.println("-/-/-/-");
        for(String st: lst3){
            System.out.println(st);
        }
    }
}
```

Копирование в подсписки можно поместить в метод или цикл, но это уже должны сделать вы, так как лучше понимаете как это должно выглядеть.

Comment: спасибо. С циклом уже разберусь.